# Reading description about Dataset in pandas

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

The below code shows error as:
**TypeError: data type "" not understood**

**The code i wrote is as below:**

```
>train = pandas.read_csv('train.csv)
>train.describe(include = ['0'])
```

Can anybody tell me where am i wrong and what is this error?

Comment: I guess this is typo, need `train.describe(include=['O'])` if want select all object columns.

Comment: Thanks! misunderstood the O as 0 :)